# MD5 shuffling with a defined pattern of numbers

Tags: php, cryptography

I've created a MD5 shuffler with a defined number pattern.  Does this make sense?  Will this make storing passwords more secure?  Is it efficient?

```
    <?php
echo "<pre>";
$md5 = "e2fc714c4727ee9395f324cd2e7f331f";
echo "Old hash: " . $md5 . "<br />";
$hash = str_split($md5, 1);
$shuffle = explode(",", "24,29,21,23,2,30,10,22,6,28,26,11,8,19,9,20,16,3,0,14,18,15,12,25,5,4,31,1,7,27,13,17");
$newhash = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < 32; $i++) {
$s = $shuffle[$i];
$newhash .= $hash[$s];
}
echo "New Hash: " . $newhash . "<br />";
$newhash = str_split($newhash, 1);
$reverse = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < 32; $i++) {
$s = $shuffle[$i];
$reverse[$s]= $newhash[$i];
}
ksort($reverse);
$reversehash = "";
foreach ($reverse as $value) {
$reversehash .= $value;
}
echo"Reversed hash: " . $reversehash . "<br />";
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Security

In addition to what [@Kid Diamond](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/61679/49695) said (don't [use md5](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52461/how-weak-is-md5-as-a-password-hashing-function), don't [write your own hashing](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own)):

You also shouldn't 'improve' [existing hashing functions](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33531/why-improvising-your-own-hash-function-out-of-existing-hash-functions-is-so-bad) yourself (in this case, shuffling doesn't make it more unsecure, but in general, it's not a good idea to change this kind of stuff yourself).

Shuffling doesn't really add that much security, as an attacker only has to look at your script to know how to shuffle themselves (it's security through obscurity). See also this discussion at [security.stackechange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24683/does-shuffling-a-hashed-password-increase-its-security).

### Performance

Why are you doing this:

> ```
> $shuffle = explode(",", "24,29,21,23,2,30,10,22,6,28,26,11,8,19,9,20,16,3,0,14,18,15,12,25,5,4,31,1,7,27,13,17");
> ```

instead of this:

```
$shuffle = [24,29,21,23,2,30,10,22,6,28,26,11,8,19,9,20,16,3,0,14,18,15,12,25,5,4,31,1,7,27,13,17];
```

The second one will definitely perform better.

You might also try to change

> ```
> $reversehash = "";
> foreach ($reverse as $value) {
>     $reversehash .= $value;
> }
> ```

to

```
$reversehash = implode("", $reverse);
```

It is definitely easier to read, and it might perform better.

### Other

- please use correct indentation. Your code is hard to read if you don't.
- naming: `$reversehash` sounds like you are reversing the hash (eg `123` -> `321`), but it is in fact the original hash, so use something like `$originalHash`.
- magic numbers: why hardcode `32` if you can just use the length of the string? If you do this, nobody will wonder if `32` is correct, and you can reuse your code for different hash functions.
- functions: I know that this is just a proof of concept, but still functions would be nice (like `shuffle()` and `unshuffle()` or similar).

Answer (score 6):

> Will this make storing passwords more secure?

Using MD5 for passwords is a bad idea, not because of its cryptographic weaknesses, but because it's fast. This means that an attacker can try billions of candidate passwords per second on a single GPU.

I wouldn't even **bother** creating my own secure hashing functions if I'm not an expert at it. There are libraries out from people who have already done all the hard work for you and have tested them thoroughly for security. [PHPass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) is one of them.

Matter of fact, if you run PHP 5.5 or greater, you can use its native function: [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

Comment: If you haven't got PHP 5.5+ but have got PHP >= v5.3.7, you can use the plain PHP version of that function (and other related functions) from https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat It will work exactly the same, just a little slower (which, in itself is not a bad thing for security)